# How to compare before and after responses for a frequency of use question in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, survey, ordinal-data

I'm trying to compare 2 survey questions, before and after an event, where the answer choices are as follows: 
Less than monthly 
Less than weekly
Once or twice a week
On most days
More than once a day

I can't figure out what would be the best way to analyze this data to see if there is a significant difference in use. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: **Paired data** (same subjects before and after, perhaps matched by ID number) **or two-sample data** (before and after responses based on two independent samples from the same population) **?**